# Как построить linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq, nhibernate

```
public IQueryable<Response> GetReadyDevices(string xin)
{
    var result = _session.Query<Device>(x => x.Organization.Xin == xin)
        .Select(c => new Response
        {
            OrganizationFullName = c.Organization.FullName,
            Id = c.Id,
            Clients = string.Join(", ", c.Clients.Select(t => t.Organization.ShortName)),
        });
    return result;
}
```

Как сформировать linq запрос чтобы, поле Clients  было заполнено через запятую кратким названием организации?

Сущности которые тут использются :

```
    public class Device: IEntity<long> {
            public virtual long Id { get; set; }
            public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }     
            public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
            public virtual ISet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
            public Device() {
                Clients = new HashSet<Client>();
            }
        }

public class Client: IEntity<long> {
        public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public virtual string Xin { get; protected set; }
        public virtual Organization Organization { get; protected set; }
        public virtual ISet<Device> Devices { get; protected set; }
        protected Client() {
            Devices = new HashSet<Device>();
        }
    }
public class Organization : IEntity<long> {
        public virtual long Id { get; }
        public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public virtual string Xin { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string FullName { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string ShortName { get; protected set; }
        public virtual double Balance { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: А сейчас это не происходит?

Comment: Сначала вытяните и материализуйте нужные данные, а потом уже склеивайте строки

Comment: Ну и напишите используемую технологию, EF у вас там или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я использую Devexpress, и мне нужно возвращать IQuerylable, но я так пробывал - ToArray потом снова AsQuerylable.  Нет, не EF  , использую Nhibernate

Comment: @iluxa1810 , А сейчас при дебаге я вижу что данные правильно формируются, но на клиентской части все пусто, пробывал туда писать простую строку:  Clients = "TEST" , то на клиенте все окей

Comment: Ок, значит Nhibernate не умеет string.Join на сервере (да и как это могло бы выглядеть?), либо материализуете сейчас и не передаете IQuerylable дальше, либо передаете IQuerylable, а склеиваете строчки где-то потом в другом месте.

Comment: надо было скинуть модельку.
по факту, должно отрабатывать правильно

Comment: @ДенисМатюшкин добавил модели в вопрос